# Solving optimization problems in python and/or R

Tags: r, optimization, python

I'm enrolled in an optimization class that teaches solutions in SAS and Risk Solver (in Excel). These, unfortunately, are not free and I'm afraid that I will not have access to them following the program. Here, I'm presenting a homework problem that we had (for which I've also included the solution in SAS). What I would like to know is which packages to use to solve these types of problems in python and R, and if possible, some example code in either of those languages.

This was a 3 part problem. This is only part 1:

---

*An oil company produces three brands of oils: Regular, Multigrade, and Supreme. Each brand of oil is composed of one or more of four crude stocks, each having a different viscosity index. The relevant data concerning the crude stocks are:*

```
Crude Stock     Viscosity Index     Cost($/barrel)      Supply per day (barrels)
1               20                  7.10                1000
2               40                  8.50                1100
3               30                  7.70                1200
40              55                  9.00                1100
```

*Each brand of oil must meet a minimum standard for viscosity index, and each brand thus sells at a different price. The relevant data concerning the three brands of oil are:*

```
Brand           Min. Viscosity Index    Selling Price ($/barrel)    Daily Demand (barrels)
Regular         25                       8.50                       2000
Multigrade      35                       9.00                       1500
Supreme         50                      10.00                        750
```

*Determine an optimal production plan for a single day, assuming that all oil produced during this day can be either sold or stored at negligible cost. 
Assume that the daily demands represent potential sales. In other words, the model should contain demand ceilings (upper limits). What is the optimal profit under these assumptions?*

---

Here's the SAS solution for this part of the problem:

```
PROC OPTMODEL;
    VAR s1 >=0, s2 >=0, s3 >=0, s4 >=0, 
        m1 >=0, m2 >=0, m3 >=0, m4 >=0,
        r1 >=0, r2 >=0, r3 >=0, r4 >=0; 

    MAX profit=(10*(s1+s2+s3+s4)+9*(m1+m2+m3+m4)+8.5*(r1+r2+r3+r4))
        -(7.1*(s1+m1+r1)+8.5*(s2+m2+r2)+7.7*(s3+m3+r3)+9*(s4+m4+r4));

    CON crude1supply:   s1+m1+r1<=1000;
    CON crude2supply:   s2+m2+r2<=1100;
    CON crude3supply:   s3+m3+r3<=1200;
    CON crude4supply:   s4+m4+r4<=1100;
    CON supremedemand:  s1+s2+s3+s4<=750;
    CON multgraddemand: m1+m2+m3+m4<=1500;
    CON regulardemand:  r1+r2+r3+r4<=2000;
    CON v_supreme:      (1/(s1+s2+s3+s4))*(20*s1+40*s2+30*s3+55*s4)>=50;
    CON v_multgrad:     (1/(m1+m2+m3+m4))*(20*m1+40*m2+30*m3+55*m4)>=35;
    CON v_regular:      (1/(r1+r2+r3+r4))*(20*r1+40*r2+30*r3+55*r4)>=25;

    SOLVE;
    PRINT   s1 s2 s3 s4
            m1 m2 m3 m4
            r1 r2 r3 r4
            profit;
QUIT;
```

To restate my questions: what are the best packages to use to solve these types of problems in python and/or R? Can you provide some sample code (or resources) for how to solve this problem in python and/or R?

I've looked at scipy.optimize and at Pyomo so far, but it's unclear to me that they represent the best libraries to use.

Comment: The $best$ libraries can be highly subjective to your problem. The 'toy' mathematical programming problems you show here, should be easily solved by most off-the-shelf libraries.

Comment: Do you only need to solve linear programming problems, or more general ones?

Comment: At this point I'm just trying to figure out how to solve this type of linear problem in R or python. I realize they aren't complex realistic problems, but I'm just a student and have to start somewhere... I'm also interested in tools/libraries (opensource, preferably) that can be used to solve more general programs of this type.

Comment: There are not that many well-known open source python libraries outside `R` for mathematical programming. I have used `GLPK` in the past (and it wasn't much fun in C++); I see that there is a Python library that is called `PyMathProg` and offers GLPK-functionality through Python but I haven't used it, maybe it worth checking that. In general if you want to think *big* check the NEOS servers and the rneos package I mentioned, they are a bit of an overkill for now but they might come handy later.

Comment: Notice that while this problem is linear, to get a linear formulation you need to multiply through the (1/sum of variable) terms by the constant on the right hand side. OPTMODEL will handle this nicely, since it has a nonlinear solver, but other packages might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [CRAN Task View on Optimization and Mathematical Programming](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). I believe that the packages [linprog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linprog/index.html) and [quadprog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/index.html) will be good starting points for this kind of tasks, both have handy reference manuals on how to input  equality and inequality constraints. As you problems get bigger the [rneos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rneos/index.html) might also prove handy.

Answer (score 2):

For problems of this size and complexity, if you don't have access to SAS, I would recommend using Excel Solver, which is included at no extra charge with Excel. Depending on your version of Office you may need to perform some configuration steps, but it is there.

Most problems of commercial interest tend to be sophisticated, with data that constantly changes. Otherwise people would just solve them from experience. So you need to find a way to formulate your problem independently of the data. In the formulation you posted, if you need to change a value (e.g., the cost of crude 3), you need to go find that information in some specific place in the code.

The situation gets more dire when new crude types, or new brands are added. Now you have to change almost every line of your code. Now imagine that you had dozens of crude types, or dozens of products, or both, and more requirements on chemical composition. It gets ugly quickly.

This is why in problems of commercial interest, you probably want to invest in an Algebraic Modeling Language (AML). AMLs are specialized to separate data from model specification, so that models can scale and are easy to read. I rewrote your code above using OPTMODEL in a way that is completely data independent. None of the OPTMODEL code needs to change when your data changes. You only change the data tables at the top.

```
data crudes;
   input 
stockId visc cost supply;
   datalines;
1       20   7.10 1000
2       40   8.50 1100
3       30   7.70 1200
40      55   9.00 1100
;

data brands;
   input 
brand $    minVisc price demand;
   datalines;
Regular    25       8.50 2000
Multigrade 35       9.00 1500
Supreme    50      10.00  750
;

/* PROC OPTMODEL blending example independent of the data size */
proc optmodel;
   /* Declare inputs */
   set CRUDES;
   num visc{CRUDES}, cost{CRUDES}, supply{CRUDES};
   set<str> BRANDS;
   num minVisc{BRANDS}, price{BRANDS}, demand{BRANDS};

   /* read the data */
   read data crudes into CRUDES=[stockId] visc cost supply;
   read data brands into BRANDS=[brand] minVisc price demand;

   /* Declare Outputs. */
   /* How much of each crude to use in each blend */
   var Blend{CRUDES,BRANDS} >= 0;

   /* Declare Objective */
   maximize Profit=
      sum{ci in CRUDES, bi in BRANDS} (price[bi] - cost[ci]) * Blend[ci,bi];

   /* Define Constraints */
   con Viscosity{bi in BRANDS}:
                       sum{ci in CRUDES} visc[ci] * Blend[ci,bi] 
      >= minVisc[bi] * sum{ci in CRUDES}            Blend[ci,bi];

   con MaxDemand{bi in BRANDS}:
      sum{ci in CRUDES} Blend[ci,bi] <= demand[bi];

   con MaxSupply{ci in CRUDES}:
      sum{bi in BRANDS} Blend[ci,bi] <= supply[ci];

   /* solve */
   solve;
   print Blend;
quit;
```

AFAIK there is no R-native AML, although you can always read and write data from R fairly easily in all the major AMLs (including OPTMODEL). There are a few Python-based AMLs. PYOMO, out of Sandia, is currently the one with most promise. It is specialized for very large distributed problems of a certain kind, so don't expect the same conveniences you would expect from the commercial world, or even from most R packages.

In summary, as long as your problems are very simple, the easiest tool to use is Excel. You could use one of the R packages as well if you prefer. But if you expect the model to get serious, you will save more time and money and get far superior results by investing in a professional AML from the start than by trying to go Open Source, at least as of 2013/2014. And if you look at my profile you won't be surprised that I recommend you to go with OPTMODEL.

Comment: Hi Leo. Thank you for chiming in with code improvements. I like how you removed the 'magic numbers' from the algorithm -- something I try to do in most of my programming but haven't quite figured out how to do in SAS.

Comment: Hi Clay. You're welcome! Search "sas/or examples" for more content. Using sets requires some practice, but they are worth learning about. Most people only learn to use sets when they get thrown into the deep end of some consulting project. My only other suggestion is to multiply ratios through to linearize the model. That is probably what your instructor wants you to do for full credit. Your model works in OPTMODEL because SAS has an excellent Nonlinear Programming solver. But it won't work with some AMLs that expect linear models.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) for which there is also an [R interface](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/index.html). But you can also use it within other frameworks or packages, like Octave, Matlab or even the command line (glpsol).

One of the nicest things is the MathProg language (a subset of AMPL). So you can write your program in MathProg and run it in any of these frameworks.